# Error while extracting data from Sybase using OLE DB in SSIS

Tags: ssis, oledb, etl, sybase, advantage-database-server

I am having problems extracting data from Sybase using Advantage 11 OLE DB Provider in SSIS (2017). 
I can connect to the database, see the list of tables, and, when selecting a table as a data source I can see the columns.
However, when I click Preview (or run the data flow task), I get this error:

> The provider cannot derive parameter information from the command. 
>   Use SetParameterInfo. (Advantage OLE DB Provider)

I am using no parameters, my Data Access mode is set to Table or View (see attached screenshot)

[image]

In project properties, `Run64bitRuntime` is set to `False`.

What am I missing?   Thanks!!

Comment: Have you seen this thread? [How to resolve SQL query parameters mapping issues while using Oracle OLE DB provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540/how-to-resolve-sql-query-parameters-mapping-issues-while-using-oracle-ole-db-pro)

Comment: @JacobH, yes, thank you, but, like I said, I am not using any parameters in my query, it's a straight pull from a table..

Comment: Sounds like you've got it resolved then!

Comment: @JacobH, not at all, I am still getting the error!

Comment: @Tamila try using `SQL Command` as source and write a `SELECT * FROM Billing` query. what is the result

Comment: @Hadi, thank you, already tried it - same error..

Comment: @Tamila i am searching for this issue, and i think i found something interesting, i will provide an answer in a while. Even if i didn't worked with advantage oledb provider.

Comment: @Tamila i am really curious on how to solve this problem, since there is no enough references that you can search for. anything new??

Comment: @Hadi, nope.  Just replied below your answer (couldn't tag you there for some reason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved this, but not with OLE DB.  Instead, I used Advantage .NET Data Provider Release 11.1.  Then in Visual Studio, I used ADO.NET connection manager, where I changed provider to Advantage Data Provider and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

While searching on this issue, i found an [old official reference that is related to advantage ole db provider release 1.0 (since 2000)](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/Content.aspx?Key=17&RefNo=000720-1069), they mentioned that:

**Title:**

> "The Provider Cannot Derive Parameter Information From the Command. Use SetParameterInfo". **Occurs When Using a Client Side Cursor with OLE DB**

**Problem Description:**

> "The provider cannot derive parameter information from the command. Use SetParameterInfo" occurs when setting the CursorLocation to use a client-side with the Advantage OLE DB Provider.

**Solution:**

> This is a known issue in the 1.0 release of the Advantage OLE DB Provider, and is being looked into by the Advantage R&D team. The 1.1 release of the Advantage OLE DB Provider should have this problem fixed. Meanwhile, **set the CursorLocation to use a server-side cursor as a work around**. Server-side cursors work with the Advantage Database Server and the Advantage Local Server.

---

I searched on how to set CursorLocation to server side, maybe you have to set `Advantage Server Type` property in the connection string. Really i didn't worked with this type of connections but you can refer to the following articles to see some examples:

- [Advantage OLE DB Provider connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/advantage-ole-db-provider/)
- [Sybase Advantage connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-advantage/)

Also i found some official Microsoft articles concerning the `CursorLocation` property, but really i don't know where to change this property:

- [The Significance of Cursor Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/the-significance-of-cursor-location?view=sql-server-2017)
- [The Microsoft Cursor Service for OLE DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/the-microsoft-cursor-service-for-ole-db?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Recordset Object (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-ado?view=sql-server-2017)
- [CursorLocation Property (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cursorlocation-property-ado?view=sql-server-2017)

---

## Update 1 - OLE DB Services

Try working around with the `OLEDB Services` values in the OLEDB connection manager:

[image]

Also try to change the OLEDB Services value manually in the connectionstring referring to the following article:

- [Connection pooling in OLE DB .NET Data Provider applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/c0011827.html)

---

## Update 2 - Other Providers

Try using other providers to connect to Sybase such as **Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise Data Provider** or **ODBC**, there are many links that describe the whole process:

- [Import and Export from SQL Server to Sybase DB using SSIS](https://sunilreddyenugala.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/import-and-export-from-sql-server-to-sybase-db-using-ssis/)
- [SSIS with Sybase Connectors](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1959.ssis-with-sybase-connectors.aspx)
- [connecting to Sybase from Sqlserver SSIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0bb547e5-e6f6-4b02-859c-0051ab78f7d7/connecting-to-sybase-from-sqlserver-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [Extracting data from Sybase SQL Anywhere using SSIS through ODBC](http://supun-biz.blogspot.com/2010/11/extracting-data-from-sybase-sql.html)
- [Powerful SAP Sybase ADO.NET driver](https://www.progress.com/net/sybase)

Comment: thank you for your help.  I added Advantage Server Type property to the connection string, and it didn't help anything.  I can't find where to set Cursor Location, unfortunately, and Google has been no help..

Comment: @Tamila i added an update, check it out. I think this is all what i can do. Good luck

Comment: @Tamila you can import data from sybase using other providers check the latest update (2)

Comment: if I don't succeed with OLEDB, I will try ODBC next.  The crazy thing is I can access data from the same database using the same credentials through OLE DB provider in Excel.  It's just SSIS that's giving me grief.

Comment: @tamila why not using `Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise Data Provider` since its the official provider?

Comment: this is what we were told to use by our vendors..  I am still playing with cursors, but no luck so far.

Comment: @Tamila Hope that the issue will be solved. Good luck and hope that this answer helps even if a bit.

Comment: Nope, still the same issue, unfortunately.

Comment: @Tamila i think you should change the provider since there is a lack of documentation for advatnage oledb. Check update 2 section