# After reinstall SYBASE oledb provider it does not appear in SSIS connection manager

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb, etl, sybase

I have reinstalled Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise PC Client 12.5.4.
After that it's completely disappeared from SSIS connection manager.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: You should also consider using a higher version of client 12.5.4 is end of life with the vendor and over a decade old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use ADO.Net not OLEDB

When you need to connect to Sybase you have to add an ADO.Net connection not OLEDB:

[image]

[image]

---

### Official documentations

In the following [official documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20155.1550/html/newfesd/CIHFBDFC.htm) they mentioned that:

> Adaptive Server ADO.NET Data Provider can be integrated into SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS), allowing for native access to ADO.NET Data Provider functions.
> With the integration, you can use Adaptive Server as an:
>
> - ADO.NET Connection Manager
> - ADO.NET Source data flow component
> - ADO.NET Destination data flow component

Also in the [official download page](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-35857), they didn't mentioned OLEDB provider but they mentioned ADO.NET

---

### Import data from Sybase guides

In addition, you can check many articles found on the web describing the whole process to import data from Sybase, they all mentioned that you must use ADO.Net not OLEDB:

- [Import and Export from SQL Server to Sybase DB using SSIS](https://sunilreddyenugala.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/import-and-export-from-sql-server-to-sybase-db-using-ssis/)